# Как заменить в нескольких файлах значения, обработав их в процессе

Tags: node.js, bash

Есть директория с множеством файлов. Необходимо в файлах с расширениями .css и .sass найти все значения с пикселями (например '10px') и заменить их на значения с vh (например '0.93vh'). То-есть нужно получить из '10px' значение 10, прогнать по формуле (px / (1080 / 100)), и то что получилось на выходе вернуть на место уже с vh. (то-есть 10px в файле превратится в 0.93vh). Как это можно сделать не вручную?

Comment: У вас Винда или Линукс? Можно сделать это на `batch` или `bash` соответвенно. Можно делать в самом сборщике (если есть), наверное (никогда не интересовался такими изменениями). Можно сделать на `node.js` он имеет доступ к файловой системе. Но уж точно не с помощью JS, исправьте теги свои, чтобы вам смогли помочь более квалифицированные люди